# Reset auto_increment after deleting row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi i know this question has been asked before but i'm asking it differently, what i want is to reset the auto_increment column, after deleting a row in a table. if i have table with 51 rows and i delete row 48, i want row 49 to reset to 48,50 to 49 etc.

[image]

i have tried using alter table but that insert data where the row was deleted, i want something that will shift the order.

### -- Table structure for table `torrents`

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `torrents` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Kat_Link` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Tpb_Link` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Lime_Link` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `ImgUrl` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

what i want is to run a `select from table where ID = $id lmit 8` if the `ID` doesn't exists i get less than 8 rows.

Comment: So basically you want to renumber the rows?

Comment: Are you sure you want this? Is your code protected against a possible inconsistence in data? Doing this with a Primary Key is potentially dangerous...

Comment: @Jack Yes i want to renumber the rows

Comment: Read this before you continue trying: http://www.coderanch.com/t/569132/JDBC/databases/Update-primary-key-impossible

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on filling the gap, there's a way around to shift the later records on the table you provided.

```
SQL = "UPDATE torrents SET ID=ID-1 WHERE ID > 48";
```

To alter the table in order to reset the AI,

```
ALTER TABLE  `torrents ` AUTO_INCREMENT =51
```

Comment: I have tried using this code but the last row is not updated `$test = 'select ID from torrents where ID > 39';
$test = $db->query($test);
$b = 0;
foreach($test as $k){
 $a = 40 + $b;
 $id = $k['ID'] + 1;
 $db->exec("UPDATE torrents set ID = $a where ID = $id");
 $b = $b + 1;
}`

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be difficult to achieve that just use `limit` with your select statement, what you want is to get number of rows(e.g 8 rows) by `ID`, if that `ID` doesn't exists, your select statement is going to give you less rows than you want.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $r,$s // here you are guaranteed that you'll get 8 rows all the time
```

Comment: Thanks i've already solved the problem by using `limit` with this code `//displaying torrents
$start = 0;
$limit = 8;
if ($page_counter !== 'index.php') {
      
     $start = ($limit * $nav_counter);
} //getting all torrents
                $getTorrents = "SELECT * FROM torrents  ORDER BY ID DESC limit $start,$limit";` thanks anyway for trying to help.

Answer (score -1):

Try a trigger, I haven't touched a MySQL database in a long time, so the syntax below might be incorrect, but it presents the idea of what it's trying to achieve well enough.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE updateTableTrigger 
AFTER delete on 'torrents' 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 SET @id = old.ID
 UPDATE torrents SET ID = (@id-1) WHERE ID > @id;
END
```

Essentially it just deducts the row's ID by one after the deleted row.

So if you delete row with an ID of 5 it'll affect all rows after row of ID 5 and decrement their values by 1 to fill in the gap.

Comment: i have tried your code like this `$db->exec('delete from torrents where ID = 46');

$db->exec("CREATE OR REPLACE updateTableTrigger AFTER delete on 'torrents' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET @id = 46 UPDATE torrents SET ID = (@id-1) WHERE ID > @id; END");` and it didn't work.

Comment: Like I said, I haven't used MySQL is a while and the syntax is incorrect. Check the syntax first in a validator. I already see a mistake I made `SET @id = old.ID` should be `SET @id = old.ID;`. Try and return an SQLException error to see whats going wrong

Comment: You can't modify a different row in the same table in a trigger in MySQL.